# Are there extremely discontinuous functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Are there any functions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ with the following property:

> For any $x_0\in \Bbb R$, any $\delta >0$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|>\epsilon$.

In other words, do functions where the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ fails for *all* $x$ and $\epsilon$ exist at all?

While a proof of nonexistence or a constructive proof of existence would be preferable, something like a non-constructive proof using the axiom of choice is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes split the reals into countably many disjoint dense sets $A_n$ and let your function take value $n$ on $A_n$.

Comment: Adhvaitha just posted a more constructive answer, using an enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: @MirkoSwirko this is not as non-constructive as it might seem. Let $A_n$ for $n\geq 1$ be the set of rationals of the form $\frac m{2^n}$ with $m$ odd, and $A_0$ be all other numbers. Then this gives the same function as the "other candidate" given by Adhvaitha.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Let $(q_n)$ be some enumeration of rationals. Define $f$ as
\begin{align}
f(x) & =
\begin{cases}
n & \text{ if }x = q_n\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Another candidate is
\begin{align}
f(x) & =
\begin{cases}
n & \text{ if }x = m/2^n \text{ in simplest form}\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}