# Question about the existence of a specific function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all non-empty, open, and uncountable subset $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f(E) = \mathbb{R}$?

I have been thinking about it for a bit, but really can't think of any way to prove or disprove it. I have a hunch that if a set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open and uncountable, then there should be a bijection to $\mathbb{R}$. This may not be true, however. I'm not well versed in the more advanced concepts of cardinality, so I'm unsure if there is an uncountable set $E \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ such that there is no bijection from $E$ to $\mathbb R$.

I'm having great difficulty imagining a function with this property. I understand that proving existence doesn't imply that construction of such a function is feasible, but I want to understand if such a function even exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Darn! I searched for quite a bit and couldn't find it. Nice find. Yes, it's pretty much a duplicate. I guess his function implies mine exists, so it would be sufficient.

Comment: I also asked a very similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042358/are-there-extremely-discontinuous-functions).

Comment: I gave an explicit construction in my answer to the linked question.  You still need that every open set includes an interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The [Conway Base 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) is a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that its restriction to any open interval is surjective.